# Meteor-mongo: updating nested documents in array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a nested array of documents in meteor mongo like so:

```
{
"_id" : "XBsaRPrangiS7xmAc",
"chartData" : [
    {
        "sectionID" : ObjectId("74d5541d775e4836478edff7"),
        "sectionName" : "abc",
        "sectionData" : [more nested documents...]
    },
    {
        "sectionID" : ObjectId("c17841e1b2e46a5f4f43c41d"),
        "sectionName" : "def",
        "sectionData" : [more nested documents...]
    }
    ...more sections...
]
}
```

Based on several stackoverflow answers, I have tried to update fields (eg. chartData.sectionName) like so on the server:

```
  ChartData.update({
    '_id':'XBsaRPrangiS7xmAc',
    'chartData.sectionID': new Mongo.ObjectID("74d5541d775e4836478edff7")
  },{
    '$set': { 'chartData.sectionName': 'hello'}
  });
```

Now I'm getting an error message which says: "Exception while invoking method 'updateSectionName' MongoError: cannot use the part (chartData of chartData.sectionName) to traverse the element".

What's wrong with my code and what is the proper way to update nested documents in meteor?

Comment: You need to include the positional operator `$`. Try `'$set': { 'chartData.$.sectionName': 'hello'}`.

Comment: @Veeram I read somewhere that the positional operator doesn't work in meteor, but guess thats only on the client side. Thank you so much!